# Delete all items with restful api

Tags: rest, restful-url

I want delete all items in restful api,I already searched but didn't find anything good
I can delete items with id parameter but I need to clear all of them
Are there anyway to delete all of the items, not deleting items with id one by one

Comment: What do you want to delete? Please be specific and also share some code.

Comment: I  want delete all data of a json file (restful api), with url

Comment: Please share your code which you have tried.

Comment: There are no code, the default way to delete is : DELETE type request with this url : localhost/mydb/id . This will delete one item from database, now i want a restful url to delete all the data

Comment: Which url are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are there anyway to delete all of the items, not deleting items with id one by one

In HTTP, the semantics of a request apply only to the target-uri; so there isn't any way, for example, to craft a `DELETE` request that targets multiple resources.

But: there's no rule that each and every row in your database has to have its own dedicated resource, or that all changes to a given row in the database must pass through a single specific resource.

For instance, imagine a web page that lets you delete things.  It might look like a bit list, with check boxes next to each item.  You select the ones you want to get rid of, click the submit button, and a `POST` request arrives at the server, which looks at the contents of the request and makes the corresponding changes to the database.  *That* is a perfectly normal REST pattern that we've been using on the web for 25 years.